# How to get now() time with AM/PM in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

for example when i execute the following query

```
select now()::time
```

the result will be

```
"10:48:28.421"
```

so how to get the time with AM/PM ?? (ex. 10:48:28 AM)

NOTE : My computer's location is set to `English(United States)` and PostgreSQL Locale is also that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
Select to_char(now()::Time, 'HH12:MI:SS AM')
```

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2301)**</kbd>

*Output:*

---

```
TO_CHAR
05:00:12 AM
```

Refer **[Formatting Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)**

Answer (score 1):

use [to_char()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) and the pattern you need.